# Debugger Error

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I'm using tsWebEditor with xDebug and one of two errors pops up every minute or two even when I am not debugging and even when there are no files open for editing.

Exception from Debugger:
Connection reset by peer

Exception from Debugger:
xdebug did not return a valid length([|])

The "[|]" character is an unidentifiable character that looks kind of like I've posted here, but I have no idea what character it actually is.

I've searched the Internet and could not find this error discussed anywhere. Does anyone know what's wrong or what's causing the problem?

I do not remember doing anything unusual before this error started to occur.

Answer (score 1):

You lost the connection to the server.
the length-error is a result of the lost connection.

i guess:
it is not an error in the app you debug.
it is an communication-error between your debugging-software and the server.

Comment: Yes, but what's causing it? 

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling tsWebEditor multiple times and the error continues to occur.

It's definitely not an error in the application that I'm working on. It happens even when I am working on a different project and even when I don't have a single file open in tsWebEditor.

However, it only happens when tsWebEditor and only in tsWebEditor. 

Also, this error brings tsWebEditor to the front of all of my other open windows... so I've been interrupted a few times while just writing this message, since tsWebEditor is currently open.

Comment: Correction.... the line above should read, "However, it only happens when tsWebEditor is open and only in tsWebEditor."